# Как посчитать сумму длин двух строк

Tags: c#

```
купить фильтр для воды  // Длина строки 23
куплю фильтр для воды  // Длина строки 21
```

Сумма длин строк равняется 44. Это в c#. 
Но в блокноте за счет пробела при переносе строки 45!!! )) Когнитивный диссонанс люди) Как в шарпе посчитать вместе с этими переносами количество символов, то бишь сумму длин строк
[Картинко](http://s57.radikal.ru/i158/1405/50/bdccfd760268.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
string firstString = "купить фильтр для воды ";
string secondString = "куплю фильтр для воды";
int sum = firstString.Length + secondString.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

len(str1)+len(str2)+...+len(strN) + (N - 1)